# A proof that the definition of the arctan function in the complex plane is well-defined

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a problem with an exercise regarding the definition of the complex arctan function.

> Let $G=\mathbb{C} \setminus [-i,i]$ where $[-i,i]$ is the straight
> line segment connecting $-i $ to $i$ and $\gamma_z: [0,1] \to G$ be a
> piecewise continously differentiable curve from 1 to $z$. Let
>
> $$ F(z)=\int_{\gamma_z} \frac{1}{1+\xi^2} d \xi. $$
>
> Let $g: C \to \mathbb{C}, \ g(z)=F(z)+\frac{\pi}{4}$.
>
> a) Let $\sigma: [0,2 \pi] \to \mathbb{C}, \sigma(t)=2e^{it}$ and
> $\sigma_r: [0,2 \pi] \to \mathbb{C}, \sigma_r(t)=re^{it}+i$ for $r \in
> (0,2)$. Show that
>
> $$ \int_{\sigma} \frac{1}{1+\xi^2} d \xi=0, \int_{\sigma_r}
> \frac{1}{1+\xi^2} d \xi=\pi. $$
>
> b) Show that $F$ (and hence $g$) is well-defined (i.e. that it does not
> depend on the choice of the curve $y_z$) and holomorphic.
>
> c) Can you increase the domain of $g$ by analytic continuation?
>
> d) Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$. Show that
>
> $$ \text{tan}'(x)=1+\tan^2(x) \ \text{and} \ \tan(g(x))=x $$
>
> e) Show that $\tan(g(z))=z$ for all $z \in G$.

My problem is proving that $F$ is well-defined and holomorphic. Consider two  piecewise continously differentiable curves $\gamma_z, \delta_z$ connecting 1 and $z$. Let $f(\xi)=\frac{1}{1+\xi^2}$. Define

$$
\gamma: [0,1] \to G, \gamma(t)=
\begin{cases}
\gamma_z(2t)  & t \in \left[0,\frac{1}{2} \right] \\
\delta^{-1}_z(2t-1) & t \in \left[\frac{1}{2},1 \right] 
\end{cases}
$$

where $\delta^{-1}_z$ denotes the curve $\delta_z$ traversed from $z$ to $1$. Then $\gamma$ is piecewise continously differentiable closed curve. Consider

$$
\int_{\gamma} f(\xi) d \xi
=\int_{\gamma_z} f(\xi) d \xi+\int_{\delta^{-1}_z} f(\xi) d \xi 
=\int_{\gamma_z} f(\xi) d \xi-\int_{\delta_z} f(\xi) d \xi. 
$$

If I want to prove that $F$ is well-defined I have to show

$$
\int_{\gamma} f(\xi) d \xi=0. \tag{*}
$$

Since $\gamma$ is a closed curve, $G$ is divided into two components, one bounded and the other unbounded. If $[-i,i]$ lies in the unbounded component then the Cauchy theorem can be used to show (*). In the case where $[-i,i]$ lies in the bounded component I know that there is a subdivision

$$
0=t_0<t_1<...<t_n=1
$$

such that $\gamma$ is continously differentiable on $[t_{k-1}, t_k]$. Now I wanted to use analytic continuation to find a local antiderivative $\tilde{F}$ of $f$ running along the disk chain with the disks having the points $\gamma(t_k), \ k=0,...,n$ as centers such that

$$
\int_{\gamma([t_{k-1}, t_k])} f(\xi) d \xi=\tilde{F}(\gamma(t_k))-\tilde{F}(\gamma(t_{k-1})).
$$

Then

$$
\int_{\gamma} f(\xi) d \xi
=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{\gamma([t_{k-1}, t_k])} f(\xi) d \xi
=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \tilde{F}(\gamma(t_k))-\tilde{F}(\gamma(t_{k-1})).
$$

Since the sum on the right hand side telescopes and $\tilde{F}(\gamma(t_0))=\tilde{F}(\gamma(t_n))$ I should get (*). But is there another way to prove this?

For the holomorphicity of $F$ I wanted to use Morera's theorem. Let $\Delta \subset G$ be a triangle. Then using the identity $\frac{1}{1+\xi^2}=\frac{i}{2} \left(\frac{1}{\xi+i}-\frac{1}{\xi-i}\right)$ I get

$$
\oint_{\partial \Delta} F(z)dz
=\oint_{\partial \Delta} \int_{\gamma_z} f(\xi) d \xi dz
=\frac{i}{2} \left(\oint_{\partial \Delta} \int_{\gamma_z} \frac{1}{\xi+i} d \xi dz 
+ \oint_{\partial \Delta} \int_{\gamma_z} \frac{1}{\xi-i} d \xi dz \right). 
$$

If I can show $\oint_{\partial \Delta} \int_{\gamma_z} \frac{1}{\xi+i} d \xi dz=\oint_{\partial \Delta} \int_{\gamma_z} \frac{1}{\xi-i}d \xi dz=0$ I get $\oint_{\partial \Delta} F(z)dz=0$. By Morera's theorem $F$ will be holomorphic. I wanted to find antiderivatives for $\frac{1}{\xi+i}$ and $\frac{1}{\xi-i}$ that is holomorphic on $\Delta$ (which would give me the result immediately as could apply the Cauchy theorem to the integrals along $\partial \Delta$). But I do not see how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the indexes of both $i$ and $-i$ with respect to $\gamma$ are the same (and the same thing occurs for every $\omega\in[-i,i]$). So\begin{align}\int_\gamma\frac{\mathrm dz}{z^2+1}&=\frac1{2i}\int_\gamma\frac1{z-i}-\frac1{z+i}\,\mathrm dz\\&=\frac{2\pi i}{2i}\left(\operatorname{ind}(i,\gamma)-\operatorname{ind}(-i,\gamma)\right)\\&=0.\end{align}